# Using the qsort from cstdlib

Tags: c++, qsort

I am trying to run qsort from cstdlib. The function

> qsort( m_all_animals , numberOfAnimals() , sizeof(Animal*) , compare);

executes successfully but it doesn't sort the m_all_animals. Actually, it does nothing to the array. The underlying data structures are here

```
Animal** m_all_animals;

//the number of elements, I tested it and it works
int numberOfAnimals(){
    int result=0;
    for (int i=0;i<m_size*2;++i){
        if (m_all_animals[i]==NULL)
            break;
        ++result;
    }
    return result;
}

int compare (const void* p1, const void* p2){
        return ((Animal*) p1)->get_size()-((Animal*) p2)->get_size();
}
```

I have the following inheritance hierarchy if it helps

```
Animal<-Bear
Bear<-brown_bear
brown_bear<-white_bear
Bear<-panda_bear
Animal<-snail
```

Comment: “I am trying to run qsort from cstdlib” – why? Are you aware of `std::sort`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have to use qsort because my teacher says so. He explicitly forbids me to use std::sort.

Comment: Wonderful teacher. (Well to be fair, maybe there’s some sense in teaching this … but hmm.)

Comment: I am curious. Is your teacher attempting to teach C++, or C?

Comment: @juanchopanza Actually C course is a prerequisite for C++ course. The reason to use qsort is that we have not yet learned std::sort at C++ course but we learned qsort at the C course.

Comment: Then you should learn to forget about `qsort`, and learn about [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). You will have to do a lot of unlearning if you studied C as a prerequisite BTW.

Comment: I'll have to defend the teacher.  The students in CS need to learn both C and C++ and the teacher seems to be doing the right thing.  Some of the later classes in CS will require the use of C (Operating Systems, High Performance Computing).

Comment: @unxnut It is fine to learn both, but it doesn't mean that C has to be taught as a pre-requisite for C++. Certainly insisting on using `qsort` in a C++ program seems quite counter-productive.

Comment: What the teacher seems to be doing is to teach the features of C++ that are *restricted* to C.  So, it is not teaching C as a prerequisite to C++.  But we seem to be moving away from the original question, discussing teacher's (or curriculum's) intentions.

Comment: @unxnut “What the teacher seems to be doing is o teach the features of C++ that are restricted to C.” – precisely, and there’s a broad consensus that this is a *horrible* way of teaching C++. It’s like teaching how to drive a car, but by only showing the features that a car has in common with a horse.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Again, it is a matter of opinion.  We will have to look into some formal studies to see what is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is an array of pointers to `Animal`, so your `compare` function actually takes pointers to pointers to `Animal`:

```
int compare (const void* p1, const void* p2){
        return (*(Animal**)p1)->get_size()-(*(Animal**)p2)->get_size();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `qsort()` in C++! It is slow, not type-safe, and will wreck havoc when used on non-POD types. Use `std::sort()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your pointers are not correct.  You have an array of pointers (`Animal *`); it should be an array of `Animal` data type and not pointer if you want to use your `compare`.  Or you will need to modify `compare` to work with `Animal **`.